# JQGrid formatting date returns wrong date

Tags: jquery, xml, jqgrid

I'm using JQGrid to display my data (the server returns xml). The data seems to be OK:

```
<aux>
   <sessao>181092</sessao>
   <codFuncionario>13574</codFuncionario>
   <dataMarcacao class="sql-date">2011-10-15</dataMarcacao>
   <sequencia>1</sequencia>
   <seqHe/>
   <codPagamento/>
   <seqOcorrencia>0</seqOcorrencia>
   <tipoOcorrencia/>
  <diaSemana>SAB</diaSemana>
</aux>
<aux>
  <sessao>181092</sessao>
  <codFuncionario>13574</codFuncionario>
  <dataMarcacao class="sql-date">2011-10-16</dataMarcacao>
  <sequencia>1</sequencia>
  <seqHe/>
  <codPagamento/>
  <seqOcorrencia>0</seqOcorrencia>
  <tipoOcorrencia/>
  <diaSemana>DOM</diaSemana>
  <inconsistencias>FALTA DIA</inconsistencias>
</aux>
```

On the init of the grid I setup the format:

```
colModel:[ {name: 'dataMarcacao',
            index: 'dataMarcacao',
            width: 60,
            formatter: 'date',
            formatoptions: {newformat: 'd/m/Y', datefmt: 'Y-m-d'}},
```

What I don't understand is that the grid shows 15/10/2011 twice, instead of 16/10/2011.

How can I debug this? Maybe JQGrid bug?

I also try:

```
colModel:[ {name: 'dataMarcacao',
            index: 'dataMarcacao',
            width: 60,
            formatter: 'date',
            formatoptions: {newformat: 'Y-m-d', datefmt: 'Y-m-d'}},
```

and this gets the same wrong result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Sérgio Michels answered this in his own question, I cleaned it up below:</sup>

This seems to be a bug with PDT. Firebug shown the timestamps:

- `Date {Sat Oct 15 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)}`
- `Date {Sat Oct 15 2011 23:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)}` — this should be Oct 16!
- `Date {Mon Oct 17 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0200}`

I found out that the problem is related to the SO and the JavaScript object `Date`. In Windows, when you turn on the option to automatically update your clock time, the object `Date return your date minus one hour in your daylight saving time.

To fix this i edited `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` on line 4667:

```
j = timestamp.getUTCDate()
```

instead of `j = timestamp.getDate()`.

Answer (score 0):

In grid.locale js change the userLocalTime to true. This will give the local timezone